# Looking for sinatra ajax example

Tags: ajax, sinatra

Sorry if this has been covered.  Looking for a example of AJAX with Sinatra, specifically to get a partial and apply it to a tag in the DOM, from a javascript button handler. thx

Comment: found the first google result http://screencasts.org/episodes/ajax-website-with-sinatra-jquery

Answer (score 7):

Check out these examples:

- https://github.com/fcantelmi/sinatra_ajax/  (tiny example)
- https://github.com/crguezl/sinatra-jquery-ajax/
- http://ididitmyway.heroku.com/past/2011/2/27/ajax_in_sinatra/