# Incremental search in Sinatra App

Tags: ruby, sinatra, haml

I want to make an incremental search/real time search option in an Sinatra app that I am developing. I am using data_mapper as ORM and the html with Haml. I am experieced with Ruby, buth Sinatra is new to me.

I want a search field, where a list of results are presented when typing characters in the search field, as we know it from i.e. google. I was hoping to send back the characters from the search field to the Sinatra app to do a data_mapper query as shown in the Sinatra part below:

```
get '/car' do
    @cars = CarDb.all(:reg_nr.like => '#{chars_from_srcBox_id}%') 
    haml :car    
end
```

car.haml:

```
!!!
 %html
  %head
    %title Sinatra App
     %link(rel='stylesheet' href='views/style.css')
     %link(href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css')
  %body 
    %form{ :class => "formContainer", :action => "", :method => "post"}
      %fieldset
        %ol
          %ul(style="list-style-type:none")
            %li
              %label{:for => ":car_search"} Search Car.:
              %input{:type =>"carData", :name => "car_search", :class => "txtBox", :id=> srcBox}

    %ul(style="list-style-type:none")
      - @cars.each do |c|
        %li
         = "#{c.reg_nr} - #{c.car_make} #{c.car_model}"
```

I guess I would need some JavaScript/Coffescript to send back characters from the search field to the Sinatra app?? How do I link Sinatra with JavaScript?

I ran into gon-sinatra, could this be what I need or are there any more obvious choices?

Br Peter

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9120972/looking-for-sinatra-ajax-example

Answer (score 1):

If assume the "incremental search" and "autocomplete" are mostly same things try to combine AJAX functionality in Sinatra (you can find examples in answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9120972/looking-for-sinatra-ajax-example)) **on server** side with for example [typeahead.js](https://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/) JavaScript library **on client** side.

Here are other interesting client side libraries:

- Here you can find *true* incremental approach i.e. when suggested word fully prefilled in `input` field http://www.pengoworks.com/workshop/jquery/autocomplete.htm
- *Native jQuery UI component* http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/
- https://www.devbridge.com/sourcery/components/jquery-autocomplete/

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. Yes, typeahead.js or autocomplete is what I am looking for. But how do I use this in Sinatra for lookup in my data_mapper ORM?